# CSS are not applying to linked React library created with create-react-library

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I tried creating a UI component as a library. All the SCSS are compiled into CSS and included in the bundle but not available when rendering with the linked app. Any help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have missed adding external styling sheet. I found it while checking on example app in the library project. That needs to be added as a separate import. I wasted a few hours checking on this.

```
import '<your-library-name>/dist/index.css';
```